# Data appears in console.log, but not with in a <Text>{}</Text> tag when trying to render a FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to get some specific data to appear within some  tags but it does NOT show.  However, when I console.log the same data that I'm trying to get in the Text tags, I can see it.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
        View,
        FlatList,
        Text
        } from 'react-native'

import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { Header } from '../common';
import Config from '../Config';

export default class Costco extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            stores: [],
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        const obj = Config.costcoThree;
        const costcoArr = Object.values(obj);

        this.setState({
            stores: costcoArr,
        })
    }

    renderStores(item) {
        const navigate = this.props.navigation;
        console.log(item.branchName);
        return (
            <Text>{item.branchName}</Text>
        );
    }
    render(){
        return(

            <View>

                <Header headerText="Costco"/>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.stores}
                    renderItem={({item}) => {
                        this.renderStores(item)
                        //return<Text>{item.branchName}</Text>
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                />
            </View>

        )
    }
}
```

I've tried rendering Text two different ways.  The first, was by returning the data between Text tags within the renderItem method.  This worked perfectly.  However, when I attempt to return the function renderStores, I am not able to see the Text appear.  But the data does appear when I console.log it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a short answer you need to add `return this.renderStores(item)` in your `renderItem` method of FlatList.

if you are using curly braces {} in your function it will not return anything unless you explicitly add return statement in that.

for another workaround you can remove the curly braces and it will automatically return your `this.renderStores(item)` method.

If you need any example please let me know

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: Hey..is there any chance you could take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925487/state-does-not-change-until-the-second-button-press-adding-a-call-back-throws-a?noredirect=1#comment84857919_48925487